# Set unique term_id from custom meta keys

Tags: terms

I have a function to set a custom meta keys values to a taxanomy, term.

```
$category20 = $fields['field_52dd3aa1d6bc0']; // gps
wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $post_id, 'gps' );
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $category20, 'gps', true );
```

From GPS meta key, value is set to `Yes`. Also on other fields meta key value is the same for example `Yes` and `No`.

When i use `wp_set_object_terms` function to store a term, same values is stored under the same `term-id` identificator.

How can i fix this? Term ids is setting from slug?

Update:

This code works:

```
wp_insert_term(
  ''.$category20.'', // the term 
  'gps', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'GPS use',
    'slug' => 'gps-yes'
  )
);
```

But no more for remove:

```
wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $post_id, 'gps' );
```

Figured out, working solution to use meta key for taxanomy terms:

```
wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $post_id, 'gps' );
if (!term_exists($category20, "gps")) {
    wp_insert_term(
      ''.$category20.'', // the term 
      'gps', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'description'=> 'GPS use',
        'slug' => 'gps-yes'
      )
    );
}
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $category20, 'gps', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

The last (fourth) argument that you pass to [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) is `true`, which, "If true, tags will be appended to the object. If false, tags will replace existing tags". It sounds as though you are instructing `wp_set_object_terms()` to do, if I understand you, exactly what you *don't* want it to do. I think that you need to set the last argument to `false` or just leave it out, as `false` is the default.

Comment: Problem is here, `car/gps/yes` and `old-car/gps/yes` the theme `yes` terms is for id `6`. A rest of code use term-id for all terms, not for term parent -> term. Is there a any way to make a term labels for `yes` but slug and id for each term is different?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are asking

Comment: If i use a term for different taxanomies on the same slug, label name, then i got a same term id on each terms. IDs is not unique. The only fix to to that is make with `wp_set_object_terms` function, like `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, name, slug, 'air_conditioner', false );` with `name` and `slug` is different like name `yes` and slug `yes-gps`, if i could do that, i got a unique term slug with unique term id.